# Ténis ou sapatilhas?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, português-brasileiro

No norte de Portugal costumamos usar [sapatilhas](https://www.google.pt/search?q=sapatilhas&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=945&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtpuS_rafMAhXCfhoKHYwkC1UQ_AUIBigB#newwindow=1&tbm=isch&q=sapatilhas%20homem) quando referimos calçado de desporto. Já no sul usa-se a palavra ténis.

Qual das duas opções está correta? Estão as duas? Já agora o que se usa no Brasil?

Comment: Não me parece que seja essa a distribuição. Em Lisboa, usa-se _ténis_ (_sapatilhas_ usam os bailarinos). Mas no Algarve usa-se _sapatilhas_ para ténis também.

Comment: Claro que para o pessoal do Norte, Lisboa é capaz de ser sul... :)

Comment: @Artefacto Sim basicamente :p

Comment: No Brasil tênis são calçados com solado em 'borracha' geralmente geralmente com cadarços, visual esportivo. Sapatos são calçados geralmente em couro ou camurça, alguns com saltos.  E as sapatilhas são sapatos com solado baixo que lembram sapatilhas de balé, mas costumam ser chamadas assim se forem femininas.

Answer (score 2):

- O temo *Ténis* ou *Sapatos de Ténis* provavelmente provém dos primeiros calçados desportivos que surgiram serem especificamente adaptados para a prática de Ténis (desporto), estendendo-se posteriormente por falta alternativa a outro calçado desportivo ainda que não fosse para a prática do mesmo.
- Já o termo sapatilha está frequentemente associado, como foi referido anteriormente pelo utilizador Artefacto, a bailado, danças, ou "desportos de interior" tipo ginástica ou acrobacia como ilustrado abaixo.

[image: Sapatilha]

Por associação algum calçado feminino casual tipo "sabrina" parece frequentemente adoptar o nome de Sapatilha, provavelmente pelas semelhanças físicas, desconheço a deles qual corresponde a utilização original.

Mais uma vez provavelmente por falta de melhor termo específico foi-se estendendo o uso da palavra a qualquer outro calçado de desporto, mesmo que para outros usos.

Portanto seguindo essa linha de pensamento eu diria que tanto o termo ténis como o termo sapatilha poderá ser encarado como errado quando aplicado em geral a qualquer calçado para outros fins.

No entanto sendo de Lisboa eu uso sempre a palavra "ténis" para designar calçado de desporto em geral, e "sapatilha" para algo como ilustrado acima, mas diria que um termo mais correcto seria algo como "sapato de desporto" ou "calçado desportivo"

Penso que em linguagem corrente raramente se utilizam as anteriores expressões e ambas as opções Ténis ou Sapatilha seja perfeitamente aceitáveis e correctas.
Fica apenas esta opinião pessoal.

Comment: Em minha opinião, a resposta ficaria mais forte se 1) citasse fontes para algumas afirmações, como a de que _ténis_ provém do desporto com o mesmo nome, 2) se abstivesse de comentários como _o verdadeiro termo correto_ (_ténis_ é um termo _falso_ ou _incorreto_?), ou pelo menos que explicasse melhor o que isso significa e apresentasse argumentos para a referida condenação.

Comment: Se percebo bem o comentário da _sabrina_ (acho que a frase podia ser melhorada), estás a dizer que _sabrina_ é usado para referir a sapatilha de bailado e que _sapatilha_ é usado em vez de _sabrina_. Não creio que seja verdade. Acho que _sabrina_ é usado para referir também sapatilha de bailado, nos sítios em que _sapatilha_ refere ténis. Mas _sapatilha_ nunca é usado para referir o sapato de mulher. Posso estar errado, contudo, não costumo discutir calçado feminino…

Comment: Certamente ficaria uma melhor resposta, mas não fiz qualquer tipo de investigação, nem tenho fontes para confirmar o que escrevi. Utilizei termos como "provavelmente" e "penso que" para demonstrar alguma incerteza e a natureza pessoal e especulativa do que escrevi. Talvez deva deixar mais claro no texto que se trata de uma opinião, então.

Comment: Não sei se o termo originalmente utilizado para "sabrina" e foi estendido ao sapato de bailado/ginástica, ou vice-versa

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos em Braga usa-se mais a palavra sapatilha. Ténis é mais usado em ambiente mais formal.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois mais uma vez parece ser uma tendência regional mas penso que ambas estão correctas. Conheço inclusive pessoas de família que vieram de Angola e usam mais o termo "Keds" para denominar calçado desportivo em geral, porque na altura foi provavelmente a primeira marca que surgiu ou foi durante algum tempo a mais comum, à semelhança de usar "Maple" para sofás ou "Black&Decker" para os berbequins

Answer (score 0):

Sapatilhas são um tipo de sapato flexível ou de borracha. Ténis são um tipo particular de sapatilhas, i.e., sapatos para desporto.

Answer (score -2):

Sapatilhas são a designação universal do tipo de calçado desportivo. Caracteristicamente, confortável, resistente, leve, flexível e com sola de borracha ou outra para melhor aderência a pratica desportiva. Ténis é uma designação mais elitista de classificar um tipo de calçado especifico para a pratica do determinado desporto como o Ténis. As sapatilhas fazem parte da indumentaria do desportista dependendo do tipo de desporto e sua adaptabilidade especifica sem se designarem por algum em particular.

Comment: Eu não diria "elitista" mas simplesmente menos comum. Seria preciso relacionar o uso histórico dos dois termos com a história do desporto e do calçado. O que seria uma pesquisa algo complicada.